# Is "I'm going to be 17 years old after 3 days." correct?

Tags: word-choice, prepositional-phrases, future-tense

- **a.** I'm going to be 17 years old after 3 days.
- **b.** I'll be 17 years old after 3 days.
- **c.** I'm going to be 17 years old in 3 days.
- **d.** I'll be 17 years old in 3 days.

Which sentence is correct? and why?

Comment: They're all "correct", but (c) and (d) are more likely to actually be used. I can't see any reason to prefer (c) over (d) or vice-versa, nor can I see any reason why exact context would affect either your choice or the meaning. Use whichever you like best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c) and d) are equally correct.

"I will be 17" and "I am going to be 17" seem equal in this context.

Using "after" instead of "in" sounds much less natural. The meaning is the same, so I wouldn't say using "after" is incorrect, just that it sounds a bit odd.